# Nextjs and Sequelize Models

Tags: javascript, next.js, sequelize.js

Hello fellow problem solvers! I'm working on rebuilding an older project in Nextjs but currently scratching my head over this issue.

I'm attempting to build an association between an order and it's line items. Using the associations listed below I'm able to create the correct tables with the expected cols in Postbird but when fetching the data I'm getting the following error:

Error Message:

```
EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: lineItem is not associated to order!
```

Here's my associations located in server/index.js:

```
const conn = require("./conn");
const { Artist, LineItem, Order, Track, User, Vinyl } = require("./models");

//ASSOCIATIONS
User.hasMany(Order);
Order.belongsTo(User);

Order.hasMany(LineItem);
LineItem.belongsTo(Order);

Vinyl.hasMany(LineItem);
LineItem.belongsTo(Vinyl);

Vinyl.hasMany(Track);
Track.belongsTo(Vinyl);

Artist.hasMany(Vinyl);
Vinyl.belongsTo(Artist);

module.exports = { conn, Artist, LineItem, Order, Track, User, Vinyl };
```

And finally the api route

```
import { Order, LineItem, Vinyl, Artist } from "../../../../server/models";
import { requireToken } from "../../../../customMiddleware";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    try {
      const userOrders = await Order.findAll({
        where: { userId: req.query.id },
        include: {
          model: LineItem,
          attributes: ["id", "qty"],
          include: {
            model: Vinyl,
            attributes: ["id", "name", "stock", "price", "img"],
            include: {
              model: Artist,
              attributes: ["id", "name"],
            },
          },
        },
      });
      userOrders.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, userOrders });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: `An error has occurred. Unable to fetch user order id# ${req.query.id}.`,
        error,
      });
    }
  }
};

export default requireToken(handler);
```

I'd also like the mention that of course, this is currently working fine on the old project so I'm a little puzzled over this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

I've tried building the associations in different orders but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you migrated the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported models directly from `server/models` folder where you always get new model definitions without associations. You need to import them from `server/index` module:

```js
import { Order, LineItem, Vinyl, Artist } from "../../../../server/index";
```

Comment: It's times like these that make me rethink my life's decisions lol I appreciate your help!! =)